# Joining two tables together with multiple results in one table

Tags: mysql, sql

My tables looks like the following:

```
tbl_teams
id, teamname, created

tbl_teamstats
id, rank, rating, wins, losses, tbl_teams_id, created
```

I want to merge these two tables together based on tbl_teamstats "created desc limit 1"
for example the query

```
SELECT TS.*, T.* FROM tbl_teamstats as TS
LEFT JOIN tbl_teams as T
ON T.id = TS.tbl_teams_id
```

would return something like this

```
TS.id   TS.rank TS.rating   TS.wins TS.losses   T.id    T.teamname              T.created
14871   2       2522        168     26          2       teamname1               23/02/2017 17:55
14688   2       2540        168     25          2       teamname1               23/02/2017 17:55
2683    2       2535        167     25          2       teamname1               23/02/2017 17:55
2612    2       2529        166     25          2       teamname1               23/02/2017 17:55
2590    2       2523        165     25          2       teamname1               23/02/2017 17:55
2448    2       2517        164     25          2       teamname1               23/02/2017 17:55
2346    2       2511        163     25          2       teamname1               23/02/2017 17:55
234     2       2505        162     25          2       teamname1               23/02/2017 17:55
1       1       2570        171     19          1       teamname2               23/02/2017 17:55
```

what i want it to look like:

```
TS.id   TS.rank TS.rating   TS.wins TS.losses   T.id    T.teamname              T.created
14871   2       2522        168     26          2       teamname1               23/02/2017 17:55
1       1       2570        171     19          1       teamname1               23/02/2017 17:55
```

(Only showing one result from tbl_teamstat ordered by TS.id)

Could someone please help me or point me in the right direction? Would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find max id for each `tbl_team_id` from `tbl_teamstats` in a subquery and join it with `tbl_teamstats`. Then, do the joins as you need.

```
select *
from (
    select t1.*
    from tbl_teamstats t1
    join (
        select tbl_teams_id,
            max(id) id
        from tbl_teamstats
        group by tbl_teams_id
        ) t2 on t1.tbl_teams_id = t2.tbl_teams_id
        and t1.id = t2.id
    ) ts
left join tbl_teams as T on T.id = TS.tbl_teams_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `GROUP BY` clause at the end

```
SELECT TS.*, T.* FROM tbl_teamstats as TS
LEFT JOIN tbl_teams as T
ON T.id = TS.tbl_teams_id
GROUP BY TS.rank
```